# Problems with OpenXML 2.5 XSL Transformation Word 2013 C#

Tags: c#, xslt, openxml, xslcompiledtransform, word-2013

Can anyone help me out on this problem?
I haven't done anything with OpenXML before and it has me stumped!

I have a Word Document which is an invoice.
In this document, I have the usual headers etc, plus the 'fields' which need to be populated with data from my XML dataset from SQLServer.

I took a copy of the word/document.xml from the docx and made the recommended changes to the file to convert it into an XSLT file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

becomes

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:n2="urn:hl7-org:v3"
            exclude-result-prefixes="n2 xs xsi xsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
```

and the file is terminated with

```
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then, I changed some of my 'fields' to show where I wanted the data to be merged.

All well and good......

When I ran it, I got a new file which looked OK but would not open in Word 2013. I pulled the document.xml out of the docx and tried to open that. This gave me an Unspecified Error Line 1 Column 1257.

I have since tried all sorts of things, including creating an XSLT with no merge fields, just the headers and footers set up, and I get the same thing.

I have tried several different headers with differing complexity and always get the same error.

When I trace the error, it is in this tag line

```
<w:document xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
```

which finishes with column 1257:

mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">

I have checked that the namespaces are all declared but I cannot see, or understand, what is going wrong

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Can you use the validator on your document? Either programmatically or with the Productivity tool.

Comment: I would love to know how that works, to be honest. I have literally only been looking at this for a day! Never done it before and finding it a little confusing.

That having been said, I have found a workaround. I saved the word document in 'Strict OpenXML Format' which is still a docx file and still opens and you can work on it in Word. When I run using this file, I don't get the problem which I have been experiencing.

Should I have been doing this all along?

Comment: No idea, never used 'Strict OpenXML Format' tbh, the tool i was talking about, you can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425). If you open your document in there, you can right click on your document to validate the xml code and it will tell you about the different errors. Afaik the errors with `mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14` are because of TableLooks and isn't really an error so you can ignore them. There is probably another greater error which causes your problem

Comment: Thanks for your input. As I have a workaround, and not so much time, I will stick with it for now. Maybe I will find the answer later but while it is working, I will not look so hard. Thanks again!